# Compactness of an open ball, with proper subcover

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm attempting the following from a past exam paper:

> Prove that the open ball $\mathbb{B}(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not compact (with the Euclidean metric).

My solution is to take the cover $\mathcal{U} = \{\mathbb{B}(0,1)\}$, then the only subcover $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{U}$ is $\mathcal{F}=\emptyset$ (other than $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{U}$, in which case it isn't a subcover). Clearly this $\mathcal{F}$ doesnt cover $\mathcal{B}(0,1)$ , so we have a cover with no finite subcover, so the ball isn't compact.

The model solution however takes the cover $\mathcal{U}=\{\mathbb{B}(0,r) | r \in (0,1) \}$ and then shows that a finite subcover leaves an uncovered region $\mathbb{B}(0,1) \smallsetminus \mathbb{B}(0,r_{max})$, so $\mathcal{U}$ can't have a finite subcover.

Is my solution valid, since it assumes a subcover must be a proper subset of the cover? The model solution is clear to me, but was written far lengthier than mine, so more time consuming for an exam, would my solution suffice?

Comment: Your cover is already finite; it consists of **one** open set, so it has a finite subcover, namely itself!

Comment: Why wouldn't the unit ball cover the unit ball? Where did you get the proper subset idea? Refer back to your text to make sure you are using the correct definitions.

Comment: My notes aren't clear on whether the subcover had to be a proper subset, it makes sense why they went to the extra trouble now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution does not work.  Compactness means that every open cover has a finite subcover.  Your cover consists of only one set, so every subset is also finite.

Instead, you must provide an example of an open cover so that no matter what finite subset you take, it isn't a cover.

In the solution you reference, they're providing a cover, i.e., $\mathcal{U}=\{u_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ (with $B(0,1)\subseteq\cup u_n$), but for any finite subset: $\mathcal{F}=\{u_{n_i}:i\in\{1,\cdots,m\}\}$, $B(0,1)\not\subseteq \cup u_{n_i}$.